# Material.io - some of Material design library's components aren't being rendered properly

Tags: javascript, css, material-design

I've imported [Material Design](https://material.io/develop/web/components/) library's css and js files but for some reason text field isn't working properly even though the button component below it is displayed correctly.

It looks like JS isn't getting applied at all

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/x84733/pen/yEEbjK

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
<style>@import url("https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css");</style>

<div class="mdc-text-field">
  <input type="text" id="my-text-field" class="mdc-text-field__input">
  <label class="mdc-floating-label" for="my-text-field">Hint text</label>
  <div class="mdc-line-ripple"></div>
</div>

<button class="foo-button mdc-button">Button</button>
```

`text-field` component code was taken from docs:
https://material.io/develop/web/components/input-controls/text-field/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to [here](https://material.io/develop/web/components/input-controls/text-field#styles) for how to import styles and [here](https://material.io/develop/web/docs/importing-js#automatic-instantiation) to learn how to instantiate JavaScript automatically for different components for `material.io`. For textfield, you have to import following code in your `css`:

```
@import "@material/textfield/mdc-text-field";
```

And following code to your `js`:

```
mdc.textField.MDCTextField.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-text-field'));
```

Here's the overall demonstration:

```js
mdc.textField.MDCTextField.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-text-field'));
```

```css
@import "@material/textfield/mdc-text-field";
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="mdc-text-field">
  <input type="text" id="my-text-field" class="mdc-text-field__input">
  <label class="mdc-floating-label" for="my-text-field">Hint text</label>
  <div class="mdc-line-ripple"></div>
</div>

<button class="foo-button mdc-button">Button</button>
```

And codepen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pKKPBK

Comment: Awesome, it works now! Thank you for the answer and the explanation